# python generator object for card dealer

Tags: python, generator

My question is to create a function which yields a type of card at one time. e.g. `card_dealer()` which only outputs any one combination e.g.`10S`.

My attempt is

```
def card_dealer():
    rank = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']
    suit = ['S','C','H','D']
    list3=[]
    num=0
    for i in rank[num]:
        for j in suit[num]:
            list3.append(f'{i}{j}')
            num+=1
            yield list3

next(card_dealer())
```

However this only outputs the same one combination when I keep running `next(card_dealer())`:

```
['2S']
```

How would I make it so that when I run `next(card_dealer())` I would get the next combination e.g. `2C`. I've thought about using import random to randomise rather than output a combination in order, but thats for another day!
I've tried different combinations of this code e.g. moving the yield in different indentations but it doesn't give the specific result I want.

Comment: `list3` and `num` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is how I would prefer to write this function. `card_dealer`'s job is to deal cards, not make the deck after all.

```
from random import shuffle


def card_dealer(deck):
    for card in deck:
        yield card

    yield None


ranks = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']
suits = ['S','C','H','D']

deck = [rank + suit for suit in suits for rank in ranks]
shuffle(deck)

for card in card_dealer(deck):
    print(card or "Dealer is out of cards")
```

Comment: You don't need the explicit `yield None`. When you reach the end of the generator function, `StopIteration` is automatically raised for you.

Comment: In fact, `card_dealer` isn't doing anything interesting any more. You already have a list in memory; you may as well iterate over that: `for card in deck:`

Comment: @chepner To shuffle the deck it all has to be in memory anyways, so yeah, `for card in deck` would be easier, but OP asked for a generator. `yield None` is just the api I wanted, running out of cards is not an exceptional case for a card dealer.

Comment: It's still raising `StopIteration` whether you think it's a good design or not; that's how generators *work* (and how `for` loops know when to stop iterating). It's just raising the exception after you execute `yield None`. You're just adding an unnecessary truthiness test to `card` in every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't how for loops work in Python. I'd recommend checking out this [article](https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/) for a good, thorough explanation, but the short version is that you don't need those indexes. Your current code:

```
for i in rank[num]:
```

only evaluates `rank[num]` at the beginning. Since `num` is `0`, you're only ever iterating through the *string* `'2'`, not the list that it's part of. Here's something closer to what you want:

```
def card_dealer():
    ranks = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']
    suits = ['S','C','H','D']
    for rank in ranks:
        for suit in suits:
            yield f'{rank}{suit}'

for card in card_dealer():
    print(card)
```

However, this will still deal them in order. For randomization, you could use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) and something like this. (This also uses a [list comprehension](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) and, as [suggested by chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316005/python-generator-object-for-card-dealer/70316124#comment124299307_70316124), the [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator) syntax. Each could be a standard for loop instead.)

```
import random

def card_dealer():
    ranks = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']
    suits = ['S','C','H','D']
    cards = [f'{rank}{suit}' for rank in ranks for suit in suits]
    random.shuffle(cards)
    yield from cards

for card in card_dealer():
    print(card)
```

Comment: Even simpler, you can use `yield from cards` instead of the `for` loop.